# CXF 2.6.1 Logging in jboss - exception

Tags: java, cxf, jboss5.x, slf4j

I'm trying to upgrade cxf from version 2.3.1 to version 2.6.1 in my project.

The project is a web-application which uses cxf as a web-service consumer running in jboss 5.1

The project uses slf4j logging but the dependencies are `provided` since the jboss container comes with slf4j.

I created the following file in the project:
`META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger` with a single line as its content:
`org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Slf4jLogger`  (As per [cxf](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html#DebuggingandLogging-UsingSLF4JInsteadofjava.util.logging%28since2.2.8%29) instructions)

When I run the project in jboss (stand-alone or from eclipse) I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '******' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public synchronized java.lang.Object org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4393)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
```

It seems to have something to do with the logging but when I lookup the class of the slf4j-api provided by jboss I can see that the method is correct:

```
public abstract void log(Marker paramMarker, String paramString1, int paramInt, String paramString2, Throwable paramThrowable);
```

This exception keeps the application from starting.

I can confirm that slf4j was working since all the logs were written correctly.

I tried setting slf4j as `compile` in maven but this causes other issues. I do not know how to continue. Can someone help with this?

Comment: Have you tried adding slf4j-api as a dependency with runtime scope?

Comment: @Nicola, yes I have but this adds the dependency to the lib folder of the webapp.  This creates a dependency clash with the version provided by jboss.

Comment: Still no complaints are logged, are they? I saw your other comment on adding slf4j-api and slf4j-log4j12. I expect you now see an error message about having two logging contexts; still this is more or less the way I have it working.

Comment: Yes there are complaints but I have checked the logging and everything seems to be working correctly at first glance.  So I consider this complaint more of a whine.  Though, due to this issue a lot more testing is needed than planned :(.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings) before embarking in your testing :-)

Comment: I read that and got confused.  In the server.log is says ERROR STDERR ... and on the site they talk about a warning.  Last time I checked error != warning.  I don't know if the error is supposed to be a warning or if their warning is supposed to be an error ...?!? Heh?!?

Comment: I suspect they got their logging level wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you found **exactly** this method signature org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker, java/lang/String, java/lang/String, java/lang/Object, java/lang/Throwable;) in your classpath ?. Probably jboss slf4j libs are somehow older than the ones expected to be used by fresh cxf. Also, check your classpath for libs collisions

Comment: There is only one slf4j lib in the classpath and that is the one from the client folder in jboss.  (This is version 1.5.6).  The method I show in the question is the one that comes from this api.  By the way, you missed the I in the signature.  That is the int on position three.

Comment: Well, it seems that adding slf4j-api-1.6.4 AND slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4 to the lib folder of the project fixes the issue.  I don't quiet understand why because the version provided by jboss has the correct signatures.  (Might be a classloader issue?)

Comment: Apparently I have become blind.  The signature in 1.6.* is different:`public abstract void log(Marker paramMarker, String paramString1, int paramInt, String paramString2, Object[] paramArrayOfObject, Throwable paramThrowable);`  So the jboss version is too old.  Thanks.

Comment: I haven't missed the int arg. I just copied method signature from exception (wanted but not found) which is different than the ones found in jboss slf4j api :-). Libs provided by jboss don't fill the requirements ;-). Its rather 'missing libs' issue over classloader one